Prove $\det(A+u v^T)=(1+v^T A^{-1} u) \det(A)$, where $A$ is inversible.
I encounter a problem about linear algebra while studying Kähler geometry. Maybe it's a duplicate. But I'm very curious why my method is not effective. My attempt:
$$\det(A+u v^T)=\det(A)\det(I+A^{-1}uv^T).$$
So we need to prove $\det(I+A^{-1}uv^T)=1+v^T A^{-1} u$. Then I try to find all the eigenvalues of $I+A^{-1}uv^T$.
Let $\{v_1,\cdots,v_{n-1}\}$ be perpendicular to $v$. Obviously,
$$(I+A^{-1}uv^T)v_i=v_i+A^{-1}u(v^Tv_i)=v_i.$$
So we get $n-1$ eigenvalues and they are all $1$. Therefore we need to prove the remaining eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $1+v^T A^{-1} u$.
Let $\displaystyle e=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_iv_i+x_nv$ be the eigenvector belonging to $\lambda$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda|e|^2&=e^T(I+A^{-1}uv^T)e\\
&=|e|^2+e^TA^{-1}uv^Te\\
&=|e|^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_iv_i^T+x_nv^T\right)A^{-1}uv^T(x_nv)\\
&=|e|^2+x_n|v|^2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_iv_i^T+x_nv^T\right)A^{-1}u\\
&\overset?=|e|^2+|e|^2v^T A^{-1} u\\
&=|e|^2(1+v^T A^{-1} u).
\end{align*}
I got stuck at "?". I don't know why this method is not effective. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the matrix determinant lemma and there are a number of posts about it on this site.

Given any vectors $a, b$, the matrix $ab^T$ has rank $1$, hence it has at most one nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$, which obviously corresponds to eigenvector $a$:
$$(ab^T)a = (b^Ta)a \Rightarrow \lambda = b^Ta$$
Therefore $I+ab^T$ has at most one eigenvalue that is not $1$, i.e. $1+b^Ta$, that is
$$\det(I+ab^T)=1+b^Ta$$
So $$\det(I+(A^{-1}u)v^T)=1+v^TA^{-1}u$$
